# jQuery Validation Engine does nothing

Tags: jquery-validation-engine

Below is an example of a non-working code.
Can anybody point what's missing or wrong?
I could not figure it out.
Using class="validate[required]" is also not working.
 Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
JQuery(document).ready(function(){
    JQuery("#newForm").validationEngine();
});
</script>
</head><body>

<form action="#" method="post" id="newForm">
<input data-validation-engine="validate[required]" id="field" name="field" type="text">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found it: be sure to write "jQuery" instead of "JQuery".
Also, be sure not to place form tags inside a table, or else validation engine will not work.
See [jquery ajax validation engine not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429707/jquery-ajax-validation-engine-not-working).